# Text is updated only once on button click

Tags: android, kotlin

In my project, there are some products..
I created a text beside the button, and when this button is clicked the amount of text should be increased.

My code increases the amount of text only once.

**My code:**

```
    holder.add.setOnClickListener {
        val num = 1
        val add  = num+1
        holder.amount.text = add.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the code in this way.

```
 var num = 1
    holder.add.setOnClickListener {
       
        val add  = num+1
        holder.amount.text = add.toString()
    }
```

The reason behind that, at every button click num is initialized with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Lets create a global variable num and everytime button is clicked then num will get updated

```
var num = 1

holder.rl_additvie.visibility = View.GONE
holder.addicon.setOnClickListener {
holder.rl_additvie.visibility = View.VISIBLE
holder.remmove.visibility = View.GONE

    
    num  = num+1
    holder.amount.text = num.toString()


}
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation as to why this piece of code answers OP's question ? Code-only answers are frowned upon (especially if they don't contain any comments)

Comment: tank's body . it worked ... but how let the max type for the text ?

Comment: you can accept answer if it works and explain a bit what else u wants